# How can I create an array of anything between <span> and </span> and </span> and <span> using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have code that takes this string and parses it into an array of characters:

```
var textArray = Regex.Replace(text, @"</?span( [^>]*|/)?>",    
String.Empty).Trim().ToCharArray();

<span>そ</span><span>れ</span><span>に</span><span>も</span>拘<span>わ</span><span>ら</span>もも<span>ず</span>
```

But now I need to do something different and I am not sure how to go about this. What I need is to parse a string like this into an array like this:

```
そ
れ
に
も
拘
わ
ら
もも
ず
```

Where anything in between `<span>` and `</span>` is an element in the array and also anything in between `</span>` and `<span>`.

Would appreciate any advice anyone could offer on how I can use Regex to do this:

Comment: `Regex.Split(text, @"</?span(?:\s+[^>]*|/)?>")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - When I tried this string: "其<span>れに</span>" it gives me an array with three rows: "其", "れに", "" - Do you have any idea  why it could be doing this? Thanks

Comment: So, what is the problem? Splitting with a match at the end / start of the string always leaves empty items. Add `.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now

Comment: I added more details and code to the answer. Please check, do not post the questions with the same issue.

Comment: Use matching approach. Else, if you have some real HTML, I'd rather go with HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
var textArray = Regex.Split(text, @"(?:</?span(?:\s+[^>]*)?>)+")
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

The `Regex.Split` method will split a string into chunks by the matching string occurrences. If the match occurs at the string boundary, empty items are added to the result, hence you need to use the `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))`.

The regex matches 1 or more occurrences of

- `<` - `<` char
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `span` - `span` text
- `(?:\s+[^>]*)?` - an optional sequence of 1+ whitespaces  and then 0 or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%3C%2F%3Fspan%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5B%5E%3E%5D*%29%3F%3E%29%2B&i=%3Cspan%20class%3D%22kanji-1-up%20kanji%22%3E%E3%81%BE%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22kanji-2-up%20kanji%22%3E%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8C%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E)

The non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) is important as `Regex.Split` will also add all captured substrings to the result.

Alternatively, if you want to only grab all texts in between `span` open/close tags:

```
var textArray = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?s)<span(?:\s+[^>]*)?>(.*?)</span>")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ddQMN8).

Here, `<span(?:\s+[^>]*)?>` matches `span` and all the inner part of the tag, and `(.*?)` captures the inner text and `</span>` matches the close tag.